# How do I mark translation strings as non-customized?

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

Drupal 8 distinguishes between "customized" and "non-customized" translations.

A customized translation is a translation that has been imported from a module and then changed at `/admin/config/regional/translate`.

So, if I edit a translation that has been imported, it becomes **customized**.

What if I edited many translations, but then changed my mind and wanted to restore them to the default?

How can I revert a **customized** string into the original **non-customized** one?  (And is it possible to do this to strings in batches?)

Comment: I would locate the string in the database table `locales_target` and set **customized** to `0`. Then the next time you update the translations it will be restored to default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on 4k4's suggestion, I was able to do this with SQL:

```
drush sqlq < "UPDATE mydb.locales_target SET customized = 0 WHERE customized = 1;"
```

**Warning: This will unset the customized flag for all strings on your site, but leave the customized translations in place.  This is what I wanted, but make sure it's what you want too before running the command.  Always make a backup, etc.**